# adding item in to the dom needs tow click rather than one in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using this below function (functional component with hooks) to add items in to the Dom.
I want to keep the fontawosome icon in the code, hidden and once the user clicks on a utility div, an icon must show in UI, after the icon shows, the user can add an item in to the movements div the problem is I have to double click all the time to add that mentioned item instead of clicking once!!
any idea what is the deal with double click ?

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import StabelItem from './StabelItem';

import { icon, library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faPlusCircle} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(faPlusCircle)

function addItems() {
    // item component imported !!
    let item = [<StabelItem />]

    // Icon State !! local 
    const [icons, setIcon] = useState([]);
    // Items State !! local 
    const [stabelItem, setStabelItem] = useState({items:[]});
    
    // Show the icon so the use can add itmes + 
    const showIcon = ()=> {
    // maipulate the state so the icon can show !! 
    setIcon(<FontAwesomeIcon onClick={() => {addStabelItem()}} icon={["fas", "plus-circle"]}/>)
    }
    // add Items !! when clicking on the icon this funtion is inside of showicon !!
    const addStabelItem = () => {
        setStabelItem({items: [...stabelItem.items, ...item]})
    }

    return (
        <div className="utility" onClick={showIcon}>
        <li className="box-item" >
        <div className="flexrow" >
            <div className='number norest'>Total</div>
            <div className='number calc margin-left norest'>0</div>
        </div>
        <ul className="movements">
        {/* itmes gets added!! when icon is getting clicked */}
        {stabelItem.items}
        {/* icons Show on demand  */}
        {icons}
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should edit the function you pass to the icon like this:

```
setIcon(<FontAwesomeIcon onClick={addStabelItem} icon={["fas", "plus-circle"]}/>)
```

Comment: sorry still the same thing... I had a glitch I thought it was working if I place the showIcon function on the flex row for example it stops adding at all ... could it be something related to the tree ? or event bubbling

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the structure making the icon on show, rather than making the state showing it, so ternary operator solved the issue.

```js
function StabelBoxUtility() {
    // item component 
    let item = [<StabelItem />]
    // Icon State
    const [iconsVisble, setIconVisble] = useState(false);
    // Items State 
    const [stabelItem, setStabelItem] = useState({items:[]});
    // show Icon 
    const showIcon = () => setIconVisble(true)
    // add Items !! the icon must be on display 
    const addStabelItem = () => {
        setStabelItem({items: [...stabelItem.items, ...item]})
    }
    return (
        <div className="utility" onClick={showIcon}>
        <li className="box-item" >
        <div className="flexrow" >
            <div className='number norest'>Total</div>
            <div className='number calc margin-left norest'>0</div>
        </div>
        <ul className="movements" >
        {stabelItem.items}
        {iconsVisble ? <FontAwesomeIcon className="changable margin-left" onClick={addStabelItem} icon={["fas", "plus-circle"]} size="lg" />: null}
        </ul>  
    </li>
 
</div>
    )
}
```